# Javascript: Manipulate string to remove underscore and capitalize letter after

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I am receiving a string like so:

```
var string = "example_string"
var otherString = "example_string_two"
```

And I want to manipulate it to output like this:

```
string = "exampleString"
otherString = "ExampleStringTwo"
```

Basically, I want to find any underscore characters in a string and remove them. If there is a letter after the underscore, then it should be capitalized.

Is there a fast way to do this in regex?

Comment: Perhaps, [`.replace(/(?:^|_)([a-z])/g, function($0,$1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); })`](https://jsfiddle.net/m8xb6hf8/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look for the start of the string or underscore and replace the found part with an uppercase character.

```js
var string= 'example_string_two';

console.log(string.replace(/(^|_)./g, s => s.slice(-1).toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: Incase like me you're on a project with old post processors, es5 version `string.replace(/(^|_)./g, function (s) {
  return s.slice(-1).toUpperCase();
});`

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression like `/_([a-zA-Z])/g` will do with a proper callback function in [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). See snippet below.

```js
function camelize (dasherizedStr) {
  return dasherizedStr
    .replace(/_([a-zA-Z])/g, function (m1, m2) {
      return m2.toUpperCase()
    });
}

console.log('example_string_foo:', camelize('example_string_foo'));
console.log('foo_Bar:', camelize('foo_Bar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could use regex methods and simply replace the underscore and i'll give you an example :

```
    var string = "example_string"
    string.replace('_','');
```

But you could also do this in classic JS, which is pretty fast in on it's self
Example:

```
    var string = "example_string"
    string.split('_').join('');
```

If you are looking for something more, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace using JavaScript

```js
var string= 'example_string_two';

console.log(string.replaceAll('_', ' '))
```

**Output** : 'example string two'

Comment: OP also wrote that he wants to capitalize the letter that follows the underscore.

Answer (score -1):

you can replace any word, underscore, dashes using javascript

**here is code**

```
var str= 'example_string_two';

console.log(var newStr = str.replace("_", " "));
```

**output:**
examplestringtwo